# r search multiple strings with '&' in file names of a directory

Tags: r

I have a directory with multiple *.pdf files. I want to find files with two or more keywords/strings in the filename.

In the below example I would like to search for a file which has "trials" and "neurology" in the filename. I used following code but no result.

```
    keyword1 = "trials"
    keyword2 = "neurology"
    pattern <- c("keyword1", "keyword2")
    whichfile <- grep(
    x = list.files("~/my_documents"),
        pattern = pattern,
        value = TRUE)
```

Comment: Are you looking for presence of both the keywords or a match of just one?

Comment: Where does the ampersand fit in? The title is confusing me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
myfun=function(x){filenames = list.files(path = "~/my_documents/")
              boolvec = (grepl(pattern = x[1],x = filenames,fixed = TRUE) & grepl(pattern = x[2],x = filenames,fixed = TRUE))
              return(filenames[which(boolvec)])
}

myfun(c(keyword1,keyword2))
```

For checking `n` number of keywords:

```
keywords = c("trials","neurology","foo")
filenames = list.files(path = "~/my_documents/")
boolvec<-Reduce(function(x,y){x&y},Map(function(patt){grepl(pattern = patt,x = filenames,fixed = TRUE)},keywords))
filenames[boolvec]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that accepts an arbitrary number of patterns. Even more, they can be arbitrary regular expressions.

```
allpatterns <- function(fnames, patterns) {
  i <- sapply(fnames, function(fn) all(sapply(patterns, grepl, fn)) )
  fnames[i]
}

filenames <- c("foo.txt", "bar.R", "foo_quux.py", "quux.c", "quux.foo",
               "foo_bar", "bar.foo.cpp", "foo_bar_quux", "quux_foo.bar", "nothing")
allpatterns(filenames, c("foo", "quux"))
# [1] "foo_quux.py"  "quux.foo"     "foo_bar_quux" "quux_foo.bar"
allpatterns(filenames, c("foo", "bar"))
# [1] "foo_bar"      "bar.foo.cpp"  "foo_bar_quux" "quux_foo.bar"
allpatterns(filenames, c("foo", "bar", "quux"))
# [1] "foo_bar_quux" "quux_foo.bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

this is modified to produce a result on my computer. you don't need `grep()` and your code is searching your path for files containing the strings `"keyword1"` and `"keyword2"`.

```
keyword1 = "quote"
keyword2 = "Project"
pattern <- c(keyword1, keyword2)
whichfile<-vector()
for (i in pattern) {
whichfile <-c(whichfile,list.files(getwd(),pattern = i))
}
whichfile

[1] "quoteCloud.jpeg"         "quotecloud2.jpeg"        "quotecloud3.jpeg"        "quotecloud4.jpeg"       
[5] "Valentinequote.R"        "Project 2 Markdown.Rmd"  "Project 2 Script.R"      "Project_2_Markdown.html"
[9] "Project_4 rough.R"       "Project3.html"           "Project3.Rmd" hope this helps you.
```

Comment: I think you should correct your `keyword2`. Also, I think OP is looking for occurrence of both keywords in the filenames.

Comment: @TUSHAr I was testing something myself, since my working directory is has a bunch of randomly named files. but I will edit it to show it works with both words.

Comment: @TUSHAr corrected to reflect both. Thank you for the feedback.